# Performance related questions regarding Oracle Arrays (Collection)

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

In order to be able to implement queries such as

```
"select * from table1 where id in [some set of elements]"
```

I am using Oracle arrays.  I found the performance to be quite good. Let's say the ids are ints.  So I will create an array type:

```
create type number_varray as varray([size]) of int;
```

Then I can use a prepared statement

```
select * from table1 where id in (select * from Table(?))
```

setting the parameter to an Array type.
I have a few questions:

1. If I make size really large is there a performance hit if the number  of elements in the query is small?
2. What is the limit to size?
3. When I call conn.createOracleArray(String name, Obj[] elements) does it hit the server or does that happy after executing a query?
4. Is there a more efficient way to implement such queries in Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is more than one question, but I'll give it a try:

1. Performance is not really going to be bad if you look at answer 4
2. According to [this article](https://community.oracle.com/thread/167707) limit is 65536, but I believe if you exceed this number you do something wrong. Use temporary tables or anything similar instead
3. This is not really connected to Oracle arrays in my opinion...
4. Use `member of`, this is much more efficient way:

   ```
   select * from table1 where id member of my_number_varray;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the article link. It looks old and delving further it appears that the limit is 2^32. I have already tried 2^20 and it works.  I am not able to get your suggestion to use "member of" working in jdbc. JDBC is not PL/SQL and I don't want to write a stored procedure for this.   Have you done something similar using JDBC?

Comment: unfortunately, I did not... But what is the difference between `member of` and `in (select * from Table(?))` ? In my opinion they are both going to an SQL server as they are; `member of` is an SQL operation and not PL/SQL. What is the problem of JDBC with it?

Comment: The problem has to do with my_number_varray in that statement.  I assume that is a declared variable of type number_varray as defined in the question?  I cannot seem to do anything like that in JDBC.

Comment: [`member of` is for nested tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions006.htm#SQLRF52135), not varrays? (And the docs [suggest the table() approach is more efficient for large collections](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e11822/adobjcol.htm#ADOBJ7292) anyway).